# Batch file to copy files from folders&sub folders using a file list only if file size greater than

Tags: database, batch-file, size, jpeg, xcopy

We have images of our warehouse stock within our database.
We will pull a list of the file names for those images into a .txt file.

The content of the file-list.txt will be for example:

```
060128412948.jpg
068912475982.jpg
etc.
```

We have 3 images for each stock 2 of them are low resolution and 1 of it is a high resolution image.

I need the script to only copy the high resolution image for each stock from the folders/sub-folders into a mother directory.

This is what I have so far but this only copies the files listed in the file-list from the source destination folder.

```
@echo off

set src_folder=C:\Users\jakub.parszewski\Desktop\TT\SalesOrders\NewOrder
set dst_folder=C:\Users\jakub.parszewski\Desktop\TT\Test
set file_list=C:\Users\jakub.parszewski\Desktop\TT\File-list.txt

set maxbytesize=300000

for /f "delims=" %%A in (%file_list% do set size=%%~zA

for /f "delims=" %%f in (%file_list%) do (
    if %size% GTR %maxbytesize% 
    xcopy "%src_folder%\%%f" "%dst_folder%\"
)

pause
```

Comment: That's because you have only performed **1.**, you need to add **2.** & **3.** before the `xcopy`. I doubt very much that there are no examples of `for` loops on this site where a file size check has not been incorporated.

Comment: Could you please explain this further? I am not experience much in this and even searching for answers has given me nothing that actually worked.
I have been asked to do this for work by my manager.

Comment: If you do a search of this site, or use a search engine, you will find many examples of methods to determine a files size from a `for` loop. You could also type `for /?` into your Command prompt window and read the outputted data.

Comment: Thanks Compo, I have been searching and playing around a little bit but for a newbie it just doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

I have updated the code in my question, am I anywhere closer to where I was or am I just drifting away from what I need?

The issue I have is I need the script to first grab the name of the file from the file-list.txt and then check the size of that file.

If the size is greater than whatever then xcopy if the size is less than whatever then ignore.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the content contained within File-list.txt and explain to us how the list was generated. The more information you provide the more likely it is that you'll get a solution you're happy with. _(Your initial question was regarding jpeg files greater than 2MB, however your code is suggesting sales orders and a file sizes of 0.2861MB)_.

Comment: I have updated the question, sorry if it is hard to read and/or understand.

Hope it makes some sense if not I will keep trying to explain.

Comment: Since source and destination are the same, why not simply use [Robocopy with /min:300000](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)?

Comment: Whilst your question makes a lot more sense now and provides sufficient information for adequate answers, I'm not sure that hard-coding a file size is the most efficient way to do this. You could probably just use RoboCopy which is what replaced XCopy many years ago; this has a feature to copy only files above or below a specific size. However your code should really be determining the largest file of each group of three files and copying that one. How do you determine which files are grouped with each other?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you think about potentially better ways of achieving a more robust method, here is a `For` loop example using a method similar to your original intent.

```bat
@Echo Off

Set "src_folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\TT\SalesOrders\NewOrder"
Set "dst_folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\TT\Test"
Set "file_list=%UserProfile%\Desktop\TT\File-list.txt"
Set "maxbytesize=3000"

For /F "UseBackQ Delims=" %%A In ("%file_list%") Do For /F %%B In (
    'Where/T /F "%src_folder%":"%%~nxA" 2^>Nul'
) Do If %%B Gtr %maxbytesize% Copy "%src_folder%\%%~nxA" "%dst_folder%">Nul

Pause
```

*I used `Copy` as your `XCopy` example didn't use any options beyond a basic copy.*